# How to reference table cell in VBA formula?

Tags: excel, vba

The following formula is used in **Table 1** and refers to a constant value in **Table 2**.

```
the_sheet.Range("H" & last_row_with_data) = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!I6 / $P$26"
```

Value **P26** is the value in Row 2, Column 2 of **Table 2**. I've made it a constant but as new items are added in **Table 1** everything is shifted down a row so now it's referring to a different value. I'm not sure how to add this to my formula so it always refers to that cell in the table.

Answer (score 0):

remove the $ symbol from your formula. It will automatically align to the new cell when new columns/rows are added.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But based on how the rest of the code works this doesn't work for me

Comment: One easy way is to create tables next to each other instead of one below the other. If the tables are too big, try creating them in separate sheets so that there is room for expansion for each of them individually without affecting each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would refer to row 2, column 2 of table 2

```
ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange(2, 2)
```

This link will help you with table references  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables